# Angular Summernote - Added ability to add links to images

Tags: angularjs, summernote

I use [Summernote](https://github.com/summernote/summernote), in my angular project.
so I really use [Angular-Summernote](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote)

I want made a link to an image, i want select an picture imported and build an anchor.

It is not possible to set links to an image.
Maybe, it's possible integrate a button like the 100%,50%,25% one for an imagelink.

somethig like that
[image]

some advice?

Comment: Hi, your question is so vague, can you please ask it another way !?

Comment: @Maher is it clear now?